# Access iTunes library on Mac from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, accessibility, itunes

Is there a way I can connect to the iTunes library on Mac from my iPhone app. The functionality which is available in Remote app from apple. I beleive this is something to do with bonjour programming.

Can anyone provide me any head start and point me in the right direction to look for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://dacp.jsharkey.org) is a good place to start. He's the guy who wrote the Android remote, after reverse-engineering DACP.

Comment: @Louis Gerbarg : This appears to be obsolete beyond iTunes 10.0.1+.  Is there any updated pairing information available?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. iTunes uses a protocol called [DAAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol). While DAAP itself has been reverse engineered, the current version of iTunes uses an authentication mechanism that is not public and has not been reverse engineered.

What that means is while people can implement unauthenticated servers that iTunes can connect to, no one but Apple can currently implement clients that connect to iTunes itself.

Comment: Apparently Android does that! So there must be a way to do it from Apples sdk And I believe the protocol is DACP which is used by iTunes. Though its similar to DAAP but have something different. Somewhere down the line I believe it is doable.

Comment: DAAP streams the audio, DACP is purely for remotely controlling iTunes. So if you only need the metadata from the library and to potentially tell iTunes to start and stop playing then DACP will be fine. If you actually want the audio data it is not.

Answer (score 0):

What about installing software like Accesstunes on your computer, then use the IP in your browser !? I used to do it with my Nokia N95-8G..! I will try with the iphone in a bit to see !